# How to query from serialize Hash column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 serialize :preferences, Hash
end
```

**preferences** contains hash record...
ex:

```
{'category' => 'a', 'type' => 'b', 'published' => true}
```

**How can I do some query, where I have to return records that matched/equal to specific key-value in serialized column.**

I want to have something like:

```
.where('preferences.published' => true)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use native DB routines to query a serialized field.
The only way to do this query is to do

`User.all.select { |u| u.preferences['published'] == true }`

You only want to serialize fields when you don't want to query on it, and just expose the data 'as it'
If you need to global query on it, you should have a table UserPreference for example, with a user_id and the different preferences.

You can 'hack' it doing what @mudasobwa said `.where('preferences LIKE "%published: true%"')`, but it can be risky.

Comment: It works, but it returns Array, I still need to have Activerecord, since I'm doing a scope to this function, and join it with another scope. How can I do it?

Comment: You do what @mudasobwa said, so you have the ActiveRecord relationship. But it's not meant to be used that way. You should not query on a serialized field.

Answer (score 2):

By default Rails serializes hashes as YAML, so you can do:

```
.where('preferences LIKE "%published: true%"')
```

Comment: I get no result using the above.